# Происхождение языка

Tags: этимология, общие-вопросы, недопустимая-метка, история

Какие есть теории о происхождении языка?
То есть, должен же быть какой-то **праязык**?

Comment: Посмотрите работы Н. Хомского о врождённых лингвистических способностях организмов вида Homo sapiens.

Answer (score 1):

Любопытно то, что древние языки, например, санскрит — наиболее сложны грамматически. Язык (или языки) "развиваются" не в сторону усложнения, а в сторону примитивизации, то есть деградируют.
Установлена закономерность: чем сложнее грамматика языка, тем он древнее, и —  наоборот. Кстати, литовский, латышский и русский — наиболее близки к санскриту (из сохранившихся языков).
Обидно будет, если русские окончательно его утратят, превратив свой — в язык германской языковой группы ("американский суржик").

Answer (score 0):

Язык есть даже у социальных насекомых — вроде пчел и муравьев.
Если говорить о членораздельной речи, то для человека она стала возможна уже с 
первого представителя рода *Homo* (Homo Habilis), жившего 2,5 млн лет 
назад.
У этого человека-умелого уже был центр речи, но (из-за устройства гортани) звуков он мог произносить меньше, чем мы. Так как от них, кроме
костей и плохо обработанных камней, ничего не осталось, с уверенностью 
сказать, что они этим языком пользовались, невозможно. Также невозможно 
выяснить: язык первоначально появился у одной из групп людей и 
распространился дальше, или было несколько независимых друг от друга 
центров распространения языка. Второй вариант, по-моему, вероятнее.

Первые пиктограммы появились около 10 тыс. лет назад, и только с этих 
пор мы можем предоставить прямые доказательства наличия языка. Но 
понятно, что к тому времени разделение языков, даже если когда-то язык
был единый, уже давно произошло.

Answer (score 0):

Что такое язык? Это набор слов и их сочетания.
Что написано в Писании? «Сначала было слово...»
Суть в том, что любому действию предшествует мысль, а мысль формируется из слов, описывающих ощущения. Именно слово обладает творческой силой и способно не только описывать окружающий мир, но и создавать. Правильнее было бы спрашивать не о происхождении языка, а о происхождении слова.
Известный праязык — естественно, санскрит. Санскритские корни встречаются во всех основных языковых группах. Происхождение санскрита, как говорится, «само скрыто»: существуют лишь теории. Одна из них — это наследие погибшей працивилизации,  доказательства существования которой встречаются на всех континентах, но почему-то официально не принимаются.
Я склоняюсь к это версии.

Comment: >Известный праязык – естественно, санскрит. Санскритские корни встречаются во всех основных языковых группах.

В языковых группах **индоевропейской языковой семьи**! 

Да. В латыни, и в греческом, в славянских и балтийских языках есть слова похожие или такие же как в санскрите. **Но**, к примеру языки **американских индейцев** или **африканцев** совсем не похожи на санскрит!

Здесь много можно написать, но я не буду. Просто периодически здесь на форуме всплывает, что вот мол - от санскрита ВСЕ языки произошли! Боюсь, что это не соответствует действительности.

Comment: Индоевропейская языковая семья - это только **одна из** языковых семей мира. Да, скорее всего, предки индусов и предки русских в середине II тысячелетия до н.э говорили на похожих или очень похожих языках. НО (!) к примеру предки эскимосов в это же самое время говорили на совершенно другом языке.